# Python Selenium Script not working on crontab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cron

I have a Python Selenium Script that works fine when I manually run it on my server but when I try to run it in a .sh using Crontab(via the cron.weekly folder) I keep getting the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

I found this very weird because in my sh, before running the program, I did

export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver      (with the correct path)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The path for jobs run by cron is different than your personal path.